# Remove default fields from search response in Elasticsearch using Java API

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, filter

we are getting data from Elasticsearch using Java API, and we could not exclude a default fields of Elasticsearch ( i.e : **"_index" , "_type" , "_id"** )

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "IndexTest",
        "_type": "typeTest",
        "_id": "AVkerYWpSOWHD5ykzT4i",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Toto", ...
        }
  ]
```

we are trying with path_filter on Kibana consol :

> GET
>   IndexTest/typeTest/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source&_source=id,name

It's works good, but now we wanna do it using Java API, Any ideas

Thank you

Comment: I don't think `filter_path` is available in the Java API, only in the REST API.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think